# Create reusable appBar in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a reusable appBar in my flutter app. The right bar button of the appbar should be controlled from main UI where it is added. I am able to create appBar and use it but I am not able to change the text color of the button on the appbar. Following is my code for creating appBar:

```
    class SocialAppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  AppBarConfig appBarConfig;
  bool isEnabled = false;
  VoidCallback rightButtonClickCallback;

  SocialAppBar({@required this.appBarConfig, @required this.rightButtonClickCallback});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SocialAppBarState();
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => new Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}

class SocialAppBarState extends State<SocialAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return getAppBarWithProfilePic();
  }
  Widget getAppBarWithProfilePic() {
    return AppBar(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      centerTitle: true,
      leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          key: const Key("backButton"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }),
      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.black54, //change your color here
      ),
      titleSpacing: 0.0,
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          buildAvatar(),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 15,
          ),
          Text(widget.appBarConfig.fullName,
              style: TextStyle(color: AppColor.appbarTitleSecondaryColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))
        ],
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
            child: InkWell(
              child: AutoSizeText(
                AppLocalizations.of(context).translate(GlobalString.labelNext),
                style: TextStyle(color: widget.isEnabled ? AppColor.blue : AppColor.greyMediumDark, fontSize: 16),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              onTap: widget.rightButtonClickCallback,
            ))
      ],
    );
  }

  setNextButtonColor(){
    setState(() {

    });
  }
}
```

I am using the above appBar like following in my screen:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    appBar = SocialAppBar(appBarConfig: appBarConfig, rightButtonClickCallback: nextButtonClick);
//Next button on app bar should be enabled when following textController has any text
    _textController.addListener((){
      if (_textController.text.length > 0){
        appBar.isEnabled = true;
      }else {
        appBar.isEnabled = false;
      }
    });
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder(
      bloc: _createPostBloc,
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is CreatePostNextState) {}
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: this.appBar,
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: buildPageView(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I am able to set the Next button enable/disable with the above code but unable to change the color from Gray to Blue.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

reusable AppBar:

```
Widget appBar(String text, IconButton iconButton) {
  return AppBar(
    title: Text(
      text,
      style: AppTheme.screenTitleStyle(),
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
    leading: IconButton(icon: iconButton, onPressed: () {}),
    backgroundColor: AppTheme.mainThemeColor(),
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
  );
}
```

Use this appBar in Activity like this :

```
 appBar: appBar(
        "Change Password",
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: How do we deal with the AppTheme and iconButton not being recognized? Are there some things to import?

Comment: @JhourladEstrella AppTheme is a class created by me,In AppTheme you can localize your  colours, styles and much more and more important thing is it will be reusable you don't have to make style and fonts again and again, so that's why I localize all my styles and colours

Comment: It may be my misunderstanding, but since appBar is not a Widget class, I think it's a good idea to set appBar to PreferredSizeWidget.

Answer (score -1):

Simple fix:

```
_textController.addListener((){
  setState(() {
    if (_textController.text.length > 0){
      appBar.isEnabled = true;
    }else {
      appBar.isEnabled = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The color of the Next button remains the same.